# Editext date validation using textwatcher

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am trying to code a textwatcher that validates input date in android. My textwatcher code is below:

```
idate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // set oid value now
            try{                        
            EditText idate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pDate); //initial date
            EditText fdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SDate); //final date
            iniDate= s.toString();
            EditText inNDF = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NDF);  //numberofdays
            inndf= Integer.parseInt(inNDF.getText().toString());
            CullCowintro cfo= new CullCowintro();
            cfo.setDate();               //calculate final date
            fdate.setText((sDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "/" + 
                    sDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                    sDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            fdate.setKeyListener(null);        
            startmonth = (pDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            endmonth = (sDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));   

      }             
            catch(NumberFormatException e){}
            }

    });
```

My setDate() function is given below:

```
public void setDate()
{
    pDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    sDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    String date[] = iniDate.split("/", 3);

    try{
        month = Integer.parseInt(date[0])-1;
        if(month < 0 || month > 11)
        throw new NumberFormatException();
        day = Integer.parseInt(date[1]);
        if(day < 1 || day > 31)
        throw new NumberFormatException();
        year = Integer.parseInt(date[2]);
        if(year < 100)
        year += 2000;
        pDate.clear();
        pDate.set(year, month, day); 
        sDate.clear();
        sDate.set(year, month, day);
        sDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,inndf);

    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please enter the date as mm/dd/yyyy.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
//  return initSDate;
}
```

However, when I enter an invalid date, the app just crashes instead of going to nfe and printing the toast message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the stack trace and show what line of code causes the crash.

Comment: It seems to be due to an IndexOutOfBoundsException (because it has less than 2 slashes, so year = Integer.parseInt(date[2]); may make the bug), just catch it also with the following code after your exception.

Comment: @Gaëtan: Yes, that was the reason. I wrote a string conditional loop for that. Thanks.